# How can I pass Web Service inside export variable in angular 2 typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I need to pass JSON data fetched from server inside the **export var HEROES: Hero[ ]** function

The link is
https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-5/ts/eplnkr.html

Goto **app/mock-heroes.ts**, the file containes the below data,

```
import { Hero } from './hero';

export var HEROES: Hero[] = [
  {id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice'},
  {id: 12, name: 'Narco'},
  {id: 13, name: 'Bombasto'},
  {id: 14, name: 'Celeritas'},
  {id: 15, name: 'Magneta'},
  {id: 16, name: 'RubberMan'},
  {id: 17, name: 'Dynama'},
  {id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ'},
  {id: 19, name: 'Magma'},
  {id: 20, name: 'Tornado'}
];
```

I need this data to be fetched from server and not use the static data. How can i achieve it.

I have already fetched the data service using the below code,

```
private serviceUrl = "http://localhost:9000/service";

getServiceOne(): Observable<Track[]> {
  this.http.get(this.serviceUrl)
      .map(res => res.json());

}
```

The output is

```
[
  {id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice'},
  {id: 12, name: 'Narco'},
  {id: 13, name: 'Bombasto'},
  {id: 14, name: 'Celeritas'},
  {id: 15, name: 'Magneta'},
  {id: 16, name: 'RubberMan'},
  {id: 17, name: 'Dynama'},
  {id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ'},
  {id: 19, name: 'Magma'},
  {id: 20, name: 'Tornado'}
]
```

Just need to parse the above data to **export var HEROES: Hero [ ]**.

How can I achieve this. I am new to typescripts and I have spend 3 days looking for the output but got no results.

Comment: Did you try angular-in-memory-webapi?

Comment: will it be able to export the web api data, because this is linked to routing pages so unless it is exported the other modules won't work. That why I am stuck.

Comment: It will expose your data that you can do real http but without a real server

Comment: So is there any way that I can pass the webapi into export var HEROES variable?

Comment: No, this var is removed then

Comment: Can you tell me the procedure pass the service inside a function so that i can call the function and get the web service? because getServiceOne() does not provide the output. It shows undefined when i check it using console.log()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137102/discussion-between-akash-ryan-and-roman-c).

Answer (score 0):

You can get heroes from the server if you have a web api on the backend. If not then you can simulate web api like described in the docs. See [Simulating the web API](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html#!#simulating-the-web-api) for more info.

```ts
getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
           .toPromise()
           .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
           .catch(this.handleError);
```

if you don't want to use promises then you can use Rxjs [Observables](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html#!#observables) that you need to subscribe to get the data.

```
getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
  return this.http
           .get('app/heroes')
           .map(response => response.json().data as Hero[]);
```

and in component

```
this._heroService
    .getHeroes()      
    .subscribe(h => this.HEROES = h)
```

Comment: I have done the same thing in my code, it works perfectly when I want to display the data but that doesn't work in routing.